# Spring Boot REST API getting "Invalid Content-Type" error while using "services" in request mapping

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have created a REST API with spring boot version 1.5.17.

Whenever I am using the word `services` in request mapping I am getting "`Invalid Content-Type"` error

```
"exception": "org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException",
"message": "Could not create message from InputStream: Invalid Content-Type:application/json. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:application/json. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?",
```

Request Mapping which casuing this is `@RequestMapping("services/v1.0/operation")`

If I use anything else except `/services` , like `/service`, `/abcd`, `/api`  , all are working fine. I am really confused and not able to understand what is causing that?

==================Adding More Details ================

Configuration Classe

```
package com.xxx.xxx.api.rest.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig {

    @Value("${WS.SERVICE.USERNAME.xxxxx}")
    private String XXXXXUsername;

    @Value("${WS.SERVICE.PASSWORD.xxxxx}")
    private String XXXXPassword;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(User
                .withUsername(XXXXXUsername)
                .password(XXXXXPassword)
                .roles("USER").build());
        return manager;
    }
}
```

Controller : already using @RestController

```
 @RestController
 @ApiResponses({    @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error" ,response = ErrorMessage.class),
                @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request" ,response = ErrorMessage.class)
             })
@RequestMapping("services/v1.0/account")
public class AccountsController {
    static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccountsController.class);

    @Autowired
    AccountsFacade accountsFacade;

    @RequestMapping(path="/getXxxXxxNameAndXxxxxName",produces="application/json", consumes="application/json" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<AccountDetailsResponse> getXxxXxxNameAndXxxxxName(@Valid @RequestBody AccountDetailsRequest accountDetailsRequest ) {
        log.debug("START getXxxXxxNameAndXxxxxName : AccountDetailsRequest ({})",accountDetailsRequest);

        AccountDetailsResponse accountDetailsResponse = accountsFacade.getXxxXxxNameAndXxxxxName(accountDetailsRequest);

        log.debug("END getXxxXxxNameAndXxxxxName : accountDetailsResponse ({})", accountDetailsResponse);
        return new ResponseEntity<AccountDetailsResponse>(accountDetailsResponse,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I am using Gradle .. below is the content

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.17.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
    maven {
            credentials {
                    username "${artifactoryUser}"
                    password "${artifactoryPassword}"
                }
                url "${resolveUrl}"
          }
  }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply from: '../properties.gradle'

ext.branch="${getEnvProperties('BRANCH')}"
ext.branch_version=branch.substring(0,3)
ext.version_major=branch_version
ext.build_number=System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER") as Integer ?: 0
ext.version_patch="${getEnvProperties('VERSION_PATCH')}"
ext.semantic_version="${getEnvProperties('SEMANTIC_VERSION')}"
ext.pub_version = "${version_major}.${version_patch}-${semantic_version}"
version=''


war {

    manifest {
        archiveName = "${WAR_FILE_XXXXX_REST_APP}.war"
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': "${WAR_FILE_XXXXX_REST_APP}",
                   'Implementation-Version':"${pub_version}.${build_number}",
                   "Implementation-Timestamp": new Date(),
                   "Built-By" : 'Jenkins',
                   "Java-Version" :System.getProperty("java.version"),
                   "Java-implementor" :System.getProperty("java.vm.vendor")
    }
}

configurations {
    compile
    runtime {
                extendsFrom compile,testCompile
                exclude(group: 'org.glassfish.hk2.external', module:'asm-all-repackaged')
                exclude(group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', module:'jaxb-impl')
                exclude(group: 'sun-jaxb', module:'jaxb-impl')
                exclude(group: 'org.springframework.ws', module:'spring-oxm-tiger')
                exclude(group: 'ch.qos.logback', module:'logback-classic')
                exclude(group: 'ch.qos.logback', module:'logback-core')
                exclude(group: 'org.slf4j', module:'slf4j-nop')

                all*.exclude group: "javax.servlet", module: "servlet-api"
                all*.exclude group: "com.h2database", module: "h2"
                all*.exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
                all*.exclude group: "commons-logging", module: "commons-logging"
                all*.exclude group: "commons-logging", module: "commons-logging-api"

            }
    emma
}
dependencies {
    compile project(':OtherDependency')

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')

    compile ([group: 'xxx', name: 'InternalJar', version: '1.0'])

    compile ([group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-log4j', version: '1.3.8.RELEASE'])

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

    compile ([group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-ws', version: '4.3.17.RELEASE'])
    compile ([group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-stream', version: '4.3.17.RELEASE'])
    compile ([group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-xml', version: '4.3.17.RELEASE'])
    compile ([group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-file', version: '4.3.17.RELEASE'])
    compile ([group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-http', version: '4.3.17.RELEASE'])
    compile ([group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-ip', version: '4.3.17.RELEASE'])
    compile ([group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-stream', version: '4.3.17.RELEASE'])
    compile ([group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '3.2.8.RELEASE'])
    compile ([group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-oxm', version: '3.2.8.RELEASE'])
    compile ([group: 'org.apache.velocity', name: 'velocity', version: '1.7'])

    compile ([group: 'commons-httpclient', name: 'commons-httpclient', version: '3.1'])
    compile ([group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.3'])
    compile ([group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: '4.3.20.RELEASE'])
    compile ([group: 'org.springmodules', name:'spring-modules-jakarta-commons',version: '0.8a'])
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")

    compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.8.0')
    compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.8.0')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile ([group: 'org.springframework.ws', name: 'spring-ws-security', version: '2.2.2.RELEASE'])
                {
                    exclude(group: 'org.springframework')
                exclude(group: 'org.springframework.security')
                exclude(group:'org.slf4j',module:'log4j-over-slf4j')
                exclude(group: 'javax.xml.crypto')

                transitive = false
                }

        compile ([group: 'org.apache.ws.security', name: 'wss4j', version: '1.6.5'])
            {
            exclude(group: 'org.springframework.security')
                transitive = false
                }

        compile ([group: 'com.sun.xml.wsit', name: 'xws-security', version: '1.3.1'])
        compile ([group: 'org.apache.santuario', name: 'xmlsec', version: '1.5.4'])



        /** Test **/
        testCompile ([group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '4.3.20.RELEASE'])
                    {
                        transitive = false
                    }
        testCompile([group:'org.powermock',name:'powermock-api-mockito',version:'1.6.2'])
        testCompile([group:'org.powermock',name:'powermock-api-support',version:'1.6.2'])
        testCompile([group:'org.powermock',name:'powermock-core',version:'1.6.2'])
        testCompile([group:'org.powermock',name:'powermock-reflect',version:'1.6.2'])
        testCompile([group:'org.powermock',name:'powermock-module-junit4',version:'1.6.2'])
        testCompile([group:'org.powermock',name:'powermock-module-junit4-common',version:'1.6.2'])
        testCompile([group:'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.3'])
        testCompile([group:'commons-httpclient', name: 'commons-httpclient', version: '3.1'])
        testCompile([group:'io.rest-assured',name:'rest-assured',version:'3.0.0'])
        testCompile([group:'org.glassfish.jersey.containers',name:'jersey-container-grizzly2-http',version:'2.19'])
        testCompile([group:'org.glassfish.grizzly',name:'grizzly-http-server',version:'2.3.19'])

        testCompile([group:'junit',name:'junit',version:'4.12'])

        testCompile([group:'mysql',name:'mysql-connector-java',version:'5.1.45'])




        testRuntime ([group: 'org.mortbay.jetty', name: 'servlet-api', version: '3.0.20100224'])    

    }/*****************************************ADDED To RESOLVE THE PROPERTIES.GRADLE*********/

def String getEnvProperties(String propertyName)
{
   String resolvedPropertyName = System.getenv(propertyName);
   if (resolvedPropertyName== null && hasProperty(propertyName))
   {
      resolvedPropertyName = this.properties[propertyName]
   }
   return resolvedPropertyName
}
```

Comment: Add you pom please

Comment: Check that your configuration class is not annotated with @EnableWs. That enables SOAP, but from the `application/json` it sounds like you're trying to use ReST. Annotate your controller with @RestController.

Comment: added mroe details in the questions above

Comment: Already using RestController and not using EnableWS annotation..